# Kali Download Verification

Tags: kali-linux, gnupg

I am having difficulty getting the results I expect from the Kali Linux download verification steps below. I realize there is a Kali forum on their website but they aren't accepting new registrations right now, so here I am.

I am following the steps here (https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images/) for the MAC download. I am attempting to follow the steps under the heading "Verify the ISO using the SHA256SUMS File" if you want to ctrl+f to where I am on that link's page. As they describe, I've verified that the Kali official key is installed correctly. However, upon downloading SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg from the website linked on the page (http://cdimage.kali.org/current/), I get the following results:

```
gpg: Signature made Wed Aug 30 00:58:11 2023 MDT 
gpg:                using RSA key 44C6513A8E4FB3D30875F758ED444FF07D8D0BF6 
gpg: Good signature from "Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>" [unknown] 
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! 
gpg:      There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner. 
Primary key fingerprint: 44C6 513A 8E4F B3D3 0875  F758 ED44 4FF0 7D8D 0BF6
```

This WARNING is bothering me. I get the "good signature" message as mentioned in the tutorial, but the WARNING is also present. This seems like a problem. Is it? Does anyone with Kali/gpg experience have advice here? I want to be as certain as possible that my iso isn't being tampered with.

Comment: The output replicates the instructions here https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/download-images-securely/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning means that GnuPG **has no way to know** whether the person who signed the image is the person who was *supposed to* sign the image. Someone did sign, with an alleged name of "Kali Linux Repository", but **you** have to somehow verify that the signer is legitimate.

If you have received the key's fingerprint from some trusted source<sup>1</sup>, you can either a) manually compare it (carefully) with the fingerprint that GnuPG is showing you right now; or b) `gpg --lsign-key` the fingerprint, telling GnuPG that you're sure the key belongs to Kali Linux.

<sup>1</sup> The official website may be a trusted source, but then the question is: If someone can tamper with the files hosted on Kali's 'cdimage' webserver, consider whether they could also tamper with what you're seeing on the website. (This will be different depending on whether the ISO is being downloaded from a third-party mirror versus when it's being downloaded from a separate commercial CDN versus when it's being downloaded from literally the same machine as the website is on.)

Comment: Is there a point of procedure I don't understand as to why my previous responses here were deleted?

Comment: In considering whether someone could tamper with the website, it does seem as though they could insofar as the website is not using https, and probably more than this as well. How are we to know that the website is trustworthy? Or is this the modicum of uncertainty we have to accept when we download anything from the internet?

Comment: I don't know who keeps deleting the comments. As for the trustworthiness – *which* website did you get the fingerprint from? There are two websites involved here: the main Kali website certainly seems to use HTTPS, and only the image server does not.

Comment: I used the `wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | gpg --import` command to get the fingerprint from the Kali website. Thanks for your responsiveness!

Comment: I don't know who keeps deleting the comments.    .......... It was not me - I do not know how.

Comment: supplemental readings: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407062/gpg-list-keys-command-outputs-uid-unknown-after-importing-private-key-onto